# Exporting PDF from MySQL query results using PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, pdf-generation, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel for exporting MySQL query results in Excel and CSV formats, but I have been unable to do the same and exporting the results as PDFs.

Below is the code Im using to do this:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel;        

$headings = array('ID','Source Date','Source','Programme Name','Coder','Presenter','Format','Audio Path','Video Path');

$rowNumber = 1;
$col = 'A';
foreach($headings as $heading)
{
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$heading);
    $col++;
}

$rowNumber = 2;
while($row = $dbase->fetchrow($query))
{
    $col = 'A';

    foreach ($row as $cell) {

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell);
        $col++;
    }
    $rowNumber++;
}

//freeze pane so that the heading does not scroll
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A2');

//save as an Excel(.xls) file
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'PDF');
$objWriter->writeAllSheets();

$objWriter->save('Report.pdf');
exit();
```

What Im I doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have corrected the code. Its described below:

```
//save as a PDF file
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_PDF($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->writeAllSheets();

$objWriter->save(ABSOLUTE_MEDIA_PATH.'Report_dated_'.date('d_M_Y',time()).'.pdf');
```

Changed the last part of the code to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest 1.7.8 version of PHPExcel, then you also need a PDF Rendering library (either tcPDF, DomPDF or mPDF) that you also need to install on your server. You then need to tell PHPExcel which of those libraries you're using, and where it's installed on your server.

This is described in section 6.9.1 of the Developer Documentation, entitled "PHPExcel_Writer_PDF"

**EDIT**

You might also want to put some exception handling in your code.

Comment: I have just looked at the files within the PHPExcel folder and it is using tcPDF within the PHPExcel_Writer_PDF class which I have now used and STILL it isnt generating any PDFs.

Comment: Please give me something more to work on: if tcPDF is included in the distribution, then what version of PHPExcel are you using? Have you tried setting error logging, or any exception handling? If so, what errors are you getting, or what exceptions are being thrown?